# UnboundLocalError: local variable "xyz" referenced before assignment

Tags: python, local-variables

**UPDATE:** In response to Wooble's comment, adding a "sector = None" before the for simply returns "None". I think the issue is that the variable in the for loop is not being returned.

The following is part of a function that was running fine, until recently, when I changed a seemingly unrelated part of the code.

**#--> the only part I had changed recently was adding "stockurl" to the return statement**

I now get **UnboundLocalError: local variable "sector" referenced before assignment**, referring to the "return" line

```
for sec in root.xpath(r'''//a[re:match(@href, "http://biz.yahoo.com/p/[0-9]{1}conameu.html")]''',
                namespaces={'re': 'http://exslt.org/regular-expressions'}):
    sector = sec.text
    #print "Sector: " + sector

for ind in root.xpath(r'''//a[re:match(@href, "http://biz.yahoo.com/ic/[0-9]{1,9}.html")]''',
        namespaces={'re': 'http://exslt.org/regular-expressions'}):
    industry = ind.text
    #print "Industry: " + industry

#index          --> don't populate here
#followers  --> don't populate here

return a, b, c, d, e, f, stockurl, sector, industry
    #--> the only part I had changed recently was adding "stockurl" to the function
```

Comment: where is stockurl used/defined before this? Can you post more of the code? Also, sector is dependent on the body of the 1st for-loop executing (though that may nor may not be related)

Comment: If the first `for` doesn't execute (`root.xpath()` returns nothing), then `sector` will never get defined. Try putting `sector = None` before the for?

Comment: adding a "sector = None" before the for simply returns "None". I think the issue is that the variable in the for loop is not being returned.

Comment: @thong: No way.  If `sector` is `None` upon return, it means that the first loop didn't perform any iteration.  Which is caused by your XPath query returning an empty list.

Comment: OMFG. I just caught the error. It's something related to the stockurl. stupid if else i forgot to account for in another part of the code. must be tired! Thanks @C2H5OH! Must be tired and/or over caffeinated

Comment: See the first comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at the error message and work backwards:

> local variable "sector" referenced before assignment

That means that you are referring to `sector` but that `sector` has not been assigned, or bound, to an object.

The only assignment to `sector` is inside the body of the for `loop`. So, clearly, the body of the `for` loop was not entered. And this can only happen if the call to `root.xpath()` returns an iterable object that is empty.

Comment: I know that the comments above said the same thing, but I wanted to write a little step by step explanation as to why this is the only conclusion that explains what you reported.